# The proper way to use dynamic tabpages in C#

Tags: c#, listview, tabpage

I am developing a simple software in .NET C# for blind people that includes a phonebook.
The phonebook consists of a form with tabs in it (each tab represent a group i.e. family, friends , work etc.) and in each tab a listview that will contain the contacts in that group.
The groups are of course dynamic and user made.
My question is what is considered the proper way to handle the tabs? To create a new listview for every tab or one for all of them? how to handle the different list views? should I redefine every time the characteristics of the listview for every tab?
Would appreciate an example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to have one listview (your main list view) and then a tabcontrol which will be the host for your tabs (this is called tabbed MDI interface) .
you can create separate forms for each one of your main entities (family,friend,work,etc.) and then based on the clicked item in the main list view you can open (or activate) related tab in the the main tabcontrol .